# How Spring resolve view in REST style?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have a method in my Controller (see below):

```
@RequestMapping("person/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Person getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return personService.getById(id);
}
```

How Spring knows to which view it should return entity?

Comment: It depends on how you configure the view resolver; for example if you use the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView it will return a JSON representation of the Person object to the caller (usually when you do AJAX calls); if you configure other view resolver, Spring will act in different way

Comment: I'm using default InternalResourceViewResolver.